# Moved multisite from domain.com to localhost - Can't get it to work

Tags: wordpress

I've copied the entire wordpress folder from a server to my local machine. I have also exported and imported our MySQL database which I can access just fine.

**What settings do I need to modify in order to make the wordpress sites run on my computer?**

So far I have done this:

1. Changed `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain.com')` to `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost.com')` in **wp-config.php**
2. I've added `127.0.0.1 localhost.com` to my **hosts file**
3. I've changed the row `siteurl` to `localhost.com` in the database table **wp_options**

But I'm not sure what else to change to make it work. Whenever I try to access localhost.com I get redirected to the url listed in wp_config.php `define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.domain.com')`.

I'm using MAMP and accessing MAMP works fine. It's accessing the WP sites that trouble me. I don't know how/where to set the urls to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

When you move a Wordpress database, you need to change all the references in the DB from your old domain name to the new one. Doing this manually is tricky as a lot of the data is serialized.

Luckily, someone has written a program that will do a search and replace of every piece of data in the DB and you can get it here:

[search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

e.g. You should search for all occurrences of www.your-domain.com and replace them with localhost.com It's also worth checking for server paths, e.g. /home/my_name/public_html and change it to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs